# How do I increase the retention period of non-custom GCP metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm having a hard time finding out if this is even supported because the docs don't outright say I can increase this retention at all or not:

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy

Everything I see for increasing retention is for custom metrics- I don't want that. Can I just increase a quota or something and pay more money to have GCP keep my metrics longer than 6 weeks? Does it say somewhere in the docs if this is or is not supported?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/monitoring-metric-export

Comment: Hi, among all these metrics, which metric you want to increase retention first?

- Google Cloud metrics
- Kubernetes metrics
- ...